Unable to launch Pixel 2 API 29 - The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_29 has terminated
2024-04-11 09:55:36,884 \[ 561238\]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 29 - C:\\Users\\Amigo\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\emulator\\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_2_API_29 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300

2024-04-11 09:55:36,951 \[ 561305\]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 29 - Storing crashdata in: C:\\Users\\Amigo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\\\AndroidEmulator\\emu-crash-35.1.4.db, detection is enabled for process: 3496

2024-04-11 09:55:36,951 \[ 561305\]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 29 - Android emulator version 35.1.4.0 (build_id 11672324) (CL:N/A)

2024-04-11 09:55:36,951 \[ 561305\]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 29 - Found systemPath C:\\Users\\Amigo\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\system-images\\android-29\\google_apis_playstore\\x86\\

2024-04-11 09:55:36,999 \[ 561353\]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 29 - Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

2024-04-11 09:55:37,001 \[ 561355\]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 29 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515

2024-04-11 09:55:37,893 \[ 562247\]   INFO - STDOUT -

I am using android studio laguna and haxm is also installed and 250gb drive storage also free.

Anyone can help me out.
enter image description here
I have already tried to freeing up space and creating new avd

Please try updating to version 34.1.20. That is the most reliable stable version.
